# powerbi visual showing two filtered row data in a single visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have row which filtered like if a row value contains

[image]

That product code is given based on the string present on the product.

output: To show the price of the individual products like  X, Y, Z. and also with the combinations like Xx or xy or xz.   The combinations are unpredictable, it might be xx or yy or zx or anything.

-- need a visual for this

Comment: Update your question to include a more concrete example of what you are needing.